# Grab data from text file and store output PHP

Tags: php

I have a `test.txt` text file with the following contents:

```
Test Data: some text
Tester 2 Data: some other text
Tests 3 Data: some more
```

When I run this through my PHP file:

```
$raw = file("./test.txt");
$lineCount = count($raw);
$newFile = null;
do {
    $newFile .= "Data:\r\n";
} while(--$lineCount > 0);
file_put_contents('./test-new.txt',trim($newFile));
```

I get this:

```
Data: 
Data: 
Data:
```

My preferred output would be:

```
Data: some text
Data: some other text
Data: some more
```

What changes do I need to make to my script to get this result?

Comment: `foreach ($raw as $line_num => $line) $newFile .= "Data: $line\r\n";`

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Thanks a lot. Can you explain where this fits into my script above?

Comment: Replace the `do while` with above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code snippet will read the file line by line and put the string after `:`

```
$fn = fopen("./test.txt","r");
while(! feof($fn))  {
  $line = fgets($fn);
  $line = 'Data : '.substr($line, strpos($line, ':')+1, strlen($line));
  echo $line;
  echo '<hr>';
}
fclose($fn);
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Think I just need to run `file_put_contents`.

Comment: Yes you can make the modification to it and put the data in different file

Comment: You're the best. Thank you!! :-)